# Detect hyperlink click using app script for Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to detect an event when a user clicks on the hyperlink attached to some text in Google Docs?

Comment: Check out the event objects here. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Comment: There’s no trigger event for a hyperlink click

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to make this through Apps Script.

If you want you could try to file a Feature Request in Issue Tracker. Take a look at the [How to get help page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support).

In case you need it, here you have the [direct link to file the Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113).